# Get velocity of mouse in elm

Tags: mouseevent, elm

I need to get the velocity of mouse in elm. 
Now i have the following code which gets the position and the clicked state of the mouse in `elm 0.18`
Is it possible that we call functions inside the update to do this even so can we maintain a global variable to store the last position of the mouse ?
 
Is there any way of doing it ?

P.S I am completely new to elm.

```
import Html exposing (Html, text, div)
import Mouse exposing (..)
main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
-- MODEL
type alias Model = {
  x: Int
  , y : Int
  , isdown : Bool
}
velocity = 0
initialModel: Model
initialModel =
  { x = 0
  , y = 0
  , isdown = False
  }

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (initialModel, Cmd.none)

-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = Position Int Int
  | BtnClick Bool


update: Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd a)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Position x y->
      ({model | x = x, y = y} , Cmd.none)
    BtnClick isdown ->
        ({model | isdown = isdown} , Cmd.none)

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS

subscriptions: Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
     Sub.batch[
        Mouse.moves (\{x, y} -> Position x y)
        , Mouse.downs (\{x,y} -> BtnClick True)
        ,  Mouse.ups (\{x,y} -> BtnClick False)
        ]

view: Model -> Html a
view model =
    div[][ text (toString model) ,
        div[][text ("velocity " ++ toString  velocity)]
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elm is a pure language which means that there is no such thing as a mutable global variable. Therefore your top level `velocity` value will never, *can* never change. It will always be zero.

Instead, we keep track of changes through the model and the update function. The value that tracks your velocity will be in the model.

You are already capturing the current mouse position but in order to calculate velocity, you will need to sample that mouse position over time. Here is one direction you could go:

Update your model to include a list of the most recent sampled positions. Here I'll represent that as a tuple of size three containing a `Time` value, an `x`, and a `y` coordinate:

```elm
type alias Model = {
  x: Int
  , y : Int
  , isdown : Bool
  , samples : List (Time, Int, Int)
}

initialModel: Model
initialModel =
  { x = 0
  , y = 0
  , isdown = False
  , samples = []
  }
```

In order to keep track of the last number of sampled mouse positions, you'll need a `Msg` constructor that can take a `Time` value:

```elm
type Msg
  = Position Int Int
  | BtnClick Bool
  | Sample Time
```

You can now include a case for handling the `Sample` `Msg` inside your `update` function. In this example, I'll just hold onto the last ten samples, with the most recent sample at the head of the list:

```elm
-- in the update function...
Sample t ->
    ({ model | samples = List.take 10 ((t, model.x, model.y) :: model.samples) }, Cmd.none)
```

The way to trigger the `Sample` `Msg` with the current time is by using `Time.every` inside your subscriptions. In this example, I'll trigger the sample every 50 milliseconds:

```elm
subscriptions: Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
     Sub.batch[
        ...
        , Time.every (50 * Time.millisecond) Sample
        ]
```

As for the actual calculations involved to obtain the direction and speed to determine velocity, I'll leave that to you. This should be enough to get you headed in the right direction. Here is a [working example on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/YmRrVVvVh9a1/0).